# GeoPandas - MultiPolygon to Polygon geometry

Tags: pandas, geospatial, geopandas

`geometry` in my geopandas dataframe is of type `Polygon` and `MultiPolygon`. I'd like to convert the `MultiPolygons` to `Polygons` as I am having issues with running some spatial functions on the data.

Sample data file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/14ni2mfppt5dn7x/gdf%20%281%29.csv?dl=0

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon, Polygon
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkt
    
gdf = gpd.read_file()

# To GeoPandas
gdf['geometry'] = gdf['zip_code_geom'].apply(wkt.loads)

# Set Geometry
gdf = gdf.GeoDataFrame(df_rent_geo_v7, geometry='geometry')

# MultiPolygon to Polygon
gdf = gdf.explode(column='geometry', ignore_index=True, index_parts=False)
```

I have tried using `[explode][1]` as suggested in other similar questions, but it doesn't convert `MultiPolygons` to `Polygons`.

Comment: Hi @kms :) In your sample, I think there is no `MultiPolygon`

Comment: @Corralien I have updated the link to sample data. Can you check now?

Comment: What's wrong with `gdf.explode('geometry", ...)`? Your file is not loadable...

Comment: It's because the file is improperly formatted, it thinks that commas within the Polygon wkt are commas separating columns, so a lot of your shapes are getting broken up incorrectly.

Comment: As early as line 8 we can see that 8, 9, and 10 should all be one line, but got broken up incorrectly into multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

There are bad geometries in your example data. This will convert the valid ones and store the bad ones in the bad_geom_dict for further investigation. Explode works on the valid geoms.

```
bad_geom_dict = {}

for idx, row in gdf.iterrows():
    try:
        value = row['zip_code_geom']
        wkt.loads(value)
        gdf['geometry'] = wkt.loads(value)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        bad_geom_dict[idx] = value
```